# Ethernet Driver for Elitebook 2540p

Tags: windows, drivers

PCI/VEN_8086&DEV_4239&SUBSYS_13118086&REV_35

Its for a HP Elitebook 2540p ethernet. I've tried many drivers. I can only find dead links for the one listed above.
This is for Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: To find a download link for the driver.

Comment: They are easily available from HP. Go there and get them.  It took me two seconds of searching with Google, and the HP.com links work fine.

Comment: Try to download it. "We apologize, we were unable to find the driver description document you requested."

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "PCI/VEN_8086&DEV_4239&SUBSYS_13118086&REV_35" led me to [this post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/PCI-VEN-8086-amp-DEV-4239-amp-SUBSYS-13118086-amp-REV-35/td-p/3664532) on HP's support forum, can you try and see if one of those work for your device?

Comment: We apologize, we were unable to find the driver description document you requested.
Please select a product to view all available downloads for any selected HP product. Subscribe to driver and Support alerts using the link above to be notified when information is added.

Comment: Well, [this link](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_bd9b6997fbc7fc515f4cf4626f5c8d01=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253Dob_101142_1%257CswEnvOID%253D4059%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.tpst=bd9b6997fbc7fc515f4cf4626f5c8d01&sp4ts.oid=4173772&ac.admitted=1413739390495.876444892.199480143) works for me. Don't know what else to say.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the Hardware ID of the device, then this driver should work.

[Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software and Drivers for Windows 7 64-Bit*](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19856)

Generall rule of thumb I go by, is use the drivers from the manufacturer's website, if that doesn't work, try finding the devices manufacturers website and see if they have drivers

[HP's website for your computer](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=4138317&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4059)